# Fastest GUI for lowend computer

Tags: python, frontend

I developed a **public view** for the status of different objects, looking something like this one: http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/bridge-metrics.jpeg

It currently runs on an old machine (don't know specs now, sorry for that) using linux with running a **website in fullscreen view** in opera. The website GETs a JSON from a server an then arranages some html divs according to the stati in the JSON.

The problem is, that everything more than just displaying some html divs (e.g. blinking via css toggling in a window.setintervall callback) is very slow and sometimes hangs.

Whats the best solution to replace the web frontend but keep tasks like sending a GET request and parsing the JSON response easy? Something like python + opengl?
Or any other solutions to **get the best out of this old machine?**

Comment: I'm quite sure that the cost of a programmer rewriting the GUI in some new language exceeds the cost of a new low-end PC that could run the current HTML-based GUI flawlessly.

Comment: I have to agree with @MatteoItalia on this one. What's serving the current HTML-based GUI? You might be able to squeeze some additional performance by optimizing the stack it's running on.

Comment: as its a private project time isn't money, and so buying a new pc isn't really an option ;)